# ArgumentNullException when trying to open iBoxDb connection

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, argumentnullexception, nosql

I'm trying to get iBoxDb up and running, however, when trying to open the connection I get ArgumentNullException. The exact same code works fine on Windows Phone 8.1 **Silverlight**, but not on WP 8.1 **runtime**.
I've tried passing a path parameter instead of `""` (various combinations of `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder`) but still nothing.

Since iBoxDb has almost no documentation I'm really out of ideas :|

The code:

```
    ... 
    private readonly AutoBox _db;

    public iBoxDbRepository()
    {
        var server = new DB(1, "", true);
        _db = server.Open();
    }
    ...
```

Stacktrace:

`System.ArgumentNullException occurred
    _HResult=-2147467261
    _message=Value cannot be null.
    HResult=-2147467261
    IsTransient=false
    Message=Value cannot be null.
    Parameter name: path1
    Source=mscorlib
    ParamName=path1
StackTrace:
        at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2)
        at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.FetchOrCreateRoot()
        at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStore(String group, String id)
        at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()
        at iBoxDB.LocalServer.IO.BoxIsolatedStorageFileStreamConfig.GetIsolatedStorageFile()
        at iBoxDB.LocalServer.IO.BoxIsolatedStorageFileStreamConfig.CreateIsolatedStorageFileStream(String path, StreamAccess access)
        at iBoxDB.LocalServer.IO.BoxIsolatedStorageFileStreamConfig.CreateStream(String path, StreamAccess access)
        at q..ctor(String A_0, DatabaseConfig A_1, IBoxRecycler A_2)
        at er.a(DatabaseConfig A_0, String A_1, IBoxRecycler A_2)
        at ac..ctor(Int64 A_0, String A_1, DatabaseConfig A_2, IBoxRecycler A_3)
        at iBoxDB.LocalServer.LocalDatabaseServer.a(String A_0, Int64 A_1)
        at iBoxDB.LocalServer.LocalDatabaseServer.GetInstance(Int64 address)
        at iBoxDB.LocalServer.DB.Open(Int64 destAddr)
        at Budget.Data.iBoxDbRepository..ctor()
        at lambda_method(Closure )
        at SimpleInjector.Lifestyles.SingletonLifestyle.SingletonLifestyleRegistrationBase'1.CreateInstanceWithNullCheck()
        at System.Lazy'1.CreateValue()`

Comment: Have you tried something like: `Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "my.db");`

Comment: Yes I have, sadly it didn't change anything :(

Answer (score 1):

IsolatedStorageFile.FetchOrCreateRoot() has no parameter, nothing can do. 
WP 8.1 runtime uses different IO API, implement a new DatabaseConfig or update iBoxDB, then use 'WSDatabaseConfig'.